# Timeout error in ASP.NET mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, timeout

I am facing a weird issue, I am running Quartz jobs to fetch data from 2 different URL, but getting timeout error on one, another is working just fine. The inner exception of error that I get says 'The operation has timed out'.

One more interesting thing is that I am not getting this error on my local system, on my local, both the jobs are fetching data correctly, but on server one fails.

I also spoke to the team of the website from which I am fetching data, they told me that their configuration for both urls are same, so there is no issue at their end.

I have made some changes in my webconfig file while trying to fix this issue by reading online, but no luck yet.

I have added this line in the appSettings tag in web.config

```
<add key="SqlCommandTimeOut" value="10000000" />
```

My connection string looks like:

```
<add name="xyzDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/xyzDB.csdl|res://*/xyzDBEntities.ssdl|res://*/xyzDBEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SQL1234.xyzsite.com;initial catalog=xyzDB;User Id=xyzDB_admin;Password=xyzpassword;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

It would be great if someone can help me in sorting this out. Please let me know if more details are needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending WebClient class and overriding GetWebRequest() by setting timeout to 1 minute resolved my issue.

```
public class CustomWebClient : WebClient{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address){
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.Timeout = 60000; //1 minute timeout
        return request;
    }
}
```